# How to add a new method to a given data structure in a good way?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Lets say, we have a given external library with a tree data structure. Example: Superclass `S` with Subclass `B1` to `B5`. The subclasses may have subclasses, too.

Now I want to add an additional method for this datastructure. Normally, one would implement it by using polymorphism: Each subcluss implements the specific method.

But because we deal with an external library, we can't change the original classes. There are two alternative solutions coming in my mind:

1. Create a new class with a method which checks case for case by using `instanceof`
2. Create subclasses for each class an implement the methods there.

Which approach is the common case ? Or, is there a better alternative solution ?

Comment: maybe its an open source library and your new method is useful enough to submit as a patch or pull request?

Comment: I don't think there is one right answer, independent of the existing features of the library and the nature of the new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Visitor Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) gives you the ability to "add" new operations to existing data structures.

Comment: ..assuming that data structure is exposed outside of the parent class

Comment: @Itay thank you, this looks good for me. A little change to the original data structure has to be done, but then one is free to extend it.

Answer (score 3):

[Decorator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) may help. You can have a decorator class that extends from Class `S`. And it wraps an `S` also. You can implement your method in the decorator.

Answer (score 1):

Decorator pattern might come in handy

```
    class S2 extends S {
        S s;

        S2(S s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

         // delegate method calls to wrapped B1-B5 instance

        @Override
        void oldMethod1() {
            s.oldMethod1();
        }

...

         // add new methods
        void newMetod1() {
             ...
        }
    }
```

then use it as

```
new S2(new B1());
```

or on an existing instance of B1

```
new S2(b1);
```